# Internet connectivity in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, connectivity

How to implement continuous Internet connectivity check in flutter only once for whole app, I have almost complete app, now I need to add Internet connectivity check, Please help, thanks in advance

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return StreamBuilder<ConnectivityResult>(
          stream: connectivityStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final connectivityResult = snapshot.data;
              if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
                return MaterialApp(
                  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                  home: NoInternetConnectionScreen(),
                );
              }
              return MaterialApp(
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                home: SplashScreen(),
                routes: routes,
              );

            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {

              return MaterialApp(
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                home: NoInternetConnectionScreen(),
              );
            }

            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
      );
  }
```

Comment: Can you define "internet access"? The device offers an interface to check if you are connected to a network, but there is no way to tell whether you will reach the endpoint you want to reach, until you try. You could ping a site you trust to be up and running always (like google) but that does not guarantee that *your* site is up. To guarantee that *your* site is up and running, you need to connect and see for yourself. And then it's up to you how often you want to check and how much of the users charge and bandwidth you want to waste for that.

Answer (score 3):

The connectivity plugin states in its docs that it only provides information if there is a network connection, but not if the network is connected to the Internet

> Note that on Android, this does not guarantee connection to Internet.
> For instance, the app might have wifi access but it might be a VPN or
> a hotel WiFi with no access.

You can use

```
import 'dart:io';
...
try {
  final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
  if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
    print('connected');
  }
} on SocketException catch (_) {
  print('not connected');
}
```

Comment: I have to check on each screen?

Comment: You should always have a sepearate HttpService class which will be a non-Ui class and will do all the http calls. There you can have this only once

Comment: Also, dont check for `google.com`. The domain may not be available in few countries e.g. China. Always use `example.com` which is a dedicated official domain for this purpose

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best practice would be using connectivity plugin and wrapping your app in a stream builder

https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity

Your main screen / main page should be something like this:

```
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  Stream connectivityStream = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppStyle.backgroundColor,
      body: StreamBuilder<ConnectivityResult>(
        stream: connectivityStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final connectivityResult = snapshot.data;

            if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
              return NoConnectionPage();
            }
            return HomePage();

          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {

            return NoConnectionPage(); 
            // or some error page, but I think no connection page is what you
            // want here
          } 

          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

In NoConnectionPage() you can have a button that retries the connection with a method like this:

```
void _retryConnection() async {
      try {
        final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('example.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        print('connected');
        Navigator.of(context).pop(); // going back to MainScreen()
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      print('not connected');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Also you should use example.com instead of google.com, because in some regions google.com is unreachable

Comment: It works on only main screen, how to handle for all screens?
when I check on next screen it doesn't work

Comment: @AmirMujtaba so try to wrap Your MaterialApp/CupertinoApp in mind.dart file with the StreamBuilder and please let me know

Comment: in both case (connected or not) I return material app with different home

If connected in material app home is Splash screen which navigate auth screen, on auth screen when I turn off connection, only theme disappears not the screen itself..

Comment: Please edit your question and add there your main.dart file

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `internet_connectivity_checker` package like this :

```
class Hello extends StatelessWidget {
  const Hello({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return internetConnectivityBuilder(
      (status) {
        bool connected = status == ConnectivityStatus.online;
        return Text(connected ? "Online" : "Offline");
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Get more info about this package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connectivity_checker).